# Please help with this problem caused by autocite command

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm new to latex. It has been now almost one month trying to learn for my thesis. If I had a problem I would just type it here, and finally get the solution. But with this command `autocite` it is always problematic. It is now been 4 days trying to figure it out. Well I switched from `natbib` to `biblatex` and even `biber`. Everything works fine and I had my bibliography and I used the style `verbose`. But when I try to use the command `autocite` it doesn't show them.

On the other hand, I worked with `footcite` it gives me the citation in footnotes, which I do not understand. But I don't know why this command do not work in my `.tex` file even though I switch to `biblatex` and `biber`.

An example of what i did

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}%more common footnote style
\usepackage{fnpct}%just a cool package for nice footnotes
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{{\images}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %to disply bibliography in the table contents

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad2,natbib=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mabib.bib}

\begin{document}

Some texte\cite{cdechow_2017}  

some texte\footcite[p.12]{brown_corporat_2016}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81895/discussion-on-question-by-siham-please-help-with-this-problem-caused-by-autocite).